# jquery: How do I access the underlying DataTable inside a createdRow() callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

When a row is created, I would like to add a child row containing a `<table>`, for later population via `on.click()` + `DataTable()` + `ajax`. Pretty simple. The `createdRow()` callback seems like a great place to do this ... if I could get it to work.

`createdRow()` takes 4 parameters which appear to be the following.

- `row` - HTML element of the created row
- `data` - plain ol' JSON of the new row's data
- `dataIndex` - the row # within its table
- `cells` - DOM elements for the `<td>`s that make up the row

None of these are DataTables or child objects. Not only that, I do not seem to have a way to get at the underlying `<table>` element. Neither `$(row).closest('table')` nor `$(cells[0]).closest('table')` seem to return anything, and `$(row).parent()` doesn't work either. It seems as though the row isn't inserted into the table yet.

If the row really hasn't been inserted into the table when `createdRow()` is called, then I guess I just need to use another callback, like `initComplete()`, and iterate over rows. But `createdRow()` would be perfect, since all the data is right there in the args, so I hope I am just missing something simple and `createdRow()` can be made to work.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access a table's API object from within the table itself using one of the approaches shown [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/). So, for example,

```
$('#your_table_id_here').DataTable()
```

With this, you can do the following to create a child row:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex, cells ) {
    var myTable = $('#example').DataTable();
    myTable.row( dataIndex ).child( '<table><tr><td>some data</td></tr></table>' ).show();
  }
} );
```

This basically uses the `row()` API call with the row index number to get the row as a DataTables object (instead of a `<tr>` element).

---

If you are adding a new row via the DataTables API using `row.add()`, then you can use the row object which is returned from that function, without needing to create a new instance of the DataTable's API:

```
var row = table.row.add( ['John Doe', 'more info', ...] ).draw();
row.child( '<table><tr><td>some data</td></tr></table>' ).show();
```

The above example assumes that `table` is the variable assigned to your DataTable when the DataTable is created:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
   // your usual DataTable options here
} );
```

Adding a child to a row is typically done when the table is [initially rendered](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html), without using the `createdRow` option. I think this is the easiest way to handle things such as the open/close buttons (if you want those).

---

**Update** regarding a comment about not having access to the HTML table's ID.

Inside the `createdRow` callback function you can use `this` as a selector also: `var myTable = $( this ).DataTable();`. In this case, there is no need to know the ID of the table.

Using this, my earlier example becomes the following:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex, cells ) {
    var myTable = $( this ).DataTable();
    myTable.row( dataIndex ).child( '<table><tr><td>some data</td></tr></table>' ).show();
  }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have a reference the table id within `createdRow()`.

My initial page is a `<ul>` of `<table>`s, each of which gets turned into a DataTable during `$().ready()` and populated asynchronously via ajax. My plan was for `createdRow()` to add a child to each returned row in each returned table.

Conceptually this is the best place to do it, as opposed to inside an `on.click()` handler as in the example you mentioned. I appreciate being pointed at workarounds, but in this case I'm really only interested in if it's possible in `createdRow()`. Thank you though.

Comment: Btw my current workaround is to loop over all the rows inside `initComplete()` callback, which isn't too bad. I'm unaccustomed to a callback on an object making it so difficult to refer to the source object, but perhaps that's just how it is in this case.

Comment: Understood. You should probably update your question with this extra information. In case it helps, you can use any valid jQuery selector in place of an `id` value - for example, you can use a class name common to all your tables:  `var allMyTables = $('.some_class_name').DataTable();`. See [multiple tables](https://datatables.net/manual/api#Multiple-tables). That may or may not help you - it probably depends on the specific process by which your tables get turned into DataTables objects.

Comment: I added one more note to my answer - just in case it may also help (but I understand if it's not what you need).

Comment: The note did it :) `$(this)` was exactly what I was looking for. I knew there had to be something. Thanks!